# Is there a guide on using the Search Function?

Tags: support, feature-request, search

Up in the right corner, there is a search box. I know, based on clicking on things from profiles, that there are modifiers that can be added to the search to filter the return. At the least, you can search for only postings by unique users.

From that, is there a guide that details the parameters that can be entered to filter search results?

**EDIT** Following @waxeagle's answer:

A general guide for looking around the site exists on the help page, only shows you how to use the search function to find tags. While there is a poorly formatted "Advanced Search TIPS" drop down on the sideboard of the results display page, I'd expect educational notes about these modifiers to have their own hyperlinked wiki-esque page.

If "Advanced Search Tips" includes each available modifier, it may serve to include it as its own page via the Help center. I'd even volunteer to try and write it if that is a thing that can be done. If there are modifiers not detailed in the tips, perhaps someone else would enjoy some fun.

**TLDR:** Can a guide that precisely describes the advanced methods for using the search function be added as a link on the help center?

Comment: The search guide _is_ in the help center. It's quite detailed, and the advanced search tips are in my experience a fantastic quick reference. If there's something more you're expecting, it's not clear what that is.

Comment: A guide for looking around the help center is on the help center. A detailed guide on how to use the search function in an advanced fashion is not.

Comment: It's in the [Our Model](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange) section, right below the cutoff for being displayed on the help center landing page - #6 on the list. Is the guide inadequate in some way, or are you suggesting it should be right on the [landing page for the help center](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help)? (which is pretty reasonable)

Comment: @doppelgreener That is what I was looking for, and to top off my embarrassment, there is even a hyperlink at the bottom of the "Advanced Search Tips." I feel foolish.

Comment: They're not exactly obvious links! It's fine. If there's something that needs improvement here, those links probably could do with being a little bit more obvious. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes!

This link in the help center has a comprehensiv(ish at least) guide to using search: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/searching

There is also a handy reference that you can locate by clicking "Advanced Search Tips" in the right side bar on search results.

Re: second part of your question: we do not have that ability. If you're looking for an additional guide, MSE may have it, else you could write it as a Q&A/series of Q&As on meta here.

Comment: 1st Part Answered: Tunnel vision for 'search,' and I over look it on the help page.

Answer (score 2):

The thing I was looking for specifically, exists in the Help center. I just had a strong difficulty in finding it.

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Provides precise guidance on using each modifier available for the search function, to included the parameters and logical tools.

I attempted to delete the question, but was harried against it by the warning.